# Are requires expressions allowed to "capture" variables of the enclosing scope?

Tags: c++, c++20, requires-expression

In the following example, the function arguments are used to test with a requires expression whether an expression using them is well formed. The requires expression takes no arguments; it uses the variables in the function scope directly:

```
#include <cstddef>
#include <vector>

template<typename T>
void Resize(T &v, std::size_t const n)
{
  if constexpr (requires { v.resize(n); })
    v.resize(n);
}

template<typename T>
void Eziser(T &v, std::size_t const n)
{
  if constexpr (requires { v.eziser(n); })
    v.eziser(n);
}

int main()
{
  std::vector<int> v;

  Resize(v, 10u);
  Eziser(v, 10u);
}
```

The above code compiles with the Clang concepts branch. However, GCC10 only accepts the call to `Resize`. GCC9 ICEs. Is Clang right at accepting it?

Comment: ICE is always compiler issue.

Comment: I would say that either it should reject code if it isn't allowed to capture local variable (so both `Resize` and `Eziser` should be reject) or both function should compile. I would say clang is right.

Comment: @Jarod42 Yes. GCC behaviour is clearly buggy. I'll file a PR. I also think that Clang is right, but I would like to confirm.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, a *requires-expression* can use anything that’s in scope.  It needs only the **type** of anything it names, after all, except in a *nested-requirement* or other constant expression.  That’s true of surrounding declarations just as much as of its own (formal) parameters.

C++20 explicitly mentioned this in [expr.prim.req]/5:

> The *requirement-body* contains a sequence of *requirements*. These
> *requirements* may refer to local parameters, template parameters, and any other declarations visible from the enclosing context.

This, however, was merely a restatement of general rules, so has since been removed.

Comment: It seems that this paragraph has been removed in its entirety from the current draft. Has the situation changed somehow?

Comment: @metalfox: The rule has not changed, but that paragraph was a meaningless restatement of the grammar and of basic name lookup behavior, which is why I didn’t quote it and why it’s gone.